# Keep a number of mobs around in a certain area as long as a player is around

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want the visitors of my underwater sea-explore room, to always see at least 50 fish, but ignore fish creating if no one is around.

I can't create persistant fish since the ocean is open and they can swim away.
(It's not an aquarium. it's a glass tunnel inside the sea where people walk and see into the sea.)

Answer (score 2):

Solution with a scoreboard and two command blocks under the ground.

```
//Add a scoreboard counter nfish (in chat)
/scoreboard objectives add nfish dummy

//Add a command block  that will set that score to the number  of fishes found within 30 blocks, but only if a player is around within 25 blocks
execute if entity @p[distance=..25] store result score fake_player nfish if entity @e[type=tropical_fish, distance=..30] 

//Add a command block  that will create a random tropical fish if the above score is less than 50, but only if  a player is withing 25 blocks
execute if entity @p[distance=..25] if score fake_player nfish matches ..50 run summon tropical_fish ~ ~3 ~
```

Comment: You can remove the `run execute` parts in the second and third command. execute statements are chainable